# Who can remove my comments and why?

Tags: support, comments

Who can remove my comments and why?

Answer (score 5):

- you can
- moderators can
- the system can automatically, if your comment is flagged enough

Comment: @atch To the left of every comment, underneath the "up arrow" is the "flag" icon, which you can use to report abusive,offensive or spam comments.

Comment: Sidenote, moderators can remove comments individually or they can wipe *all* the comments on a particular post if necessary.